# Open the same workbook but different path every week

Tags: vba

I would like to open a file that is located in a different folder every week (file name remains the same but new week = new data).

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\baguette\Documents\W44\L060.xlsx"
```

The week folder is obviously W44. Is there a way I could use a cell content that would be taken into account in the code?

For example, cell A1 of sheet1 of the file the code is run from would contain the week number that I would manually key in before running the procedure.

I tried this but did not work :

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\baguette\Documents\& ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")\L060.xlsx"
```

I guess it was a bit rash.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to your solution. Just try below-

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\baguette\Documents\" & _
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1") & _
            "\L060.xlsx"
```

You can decorate code using string type variable. Check below sub.

```
Sub OpenSpecificFile()
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim WeekFolder As String

    FolderPath = "C:\Users\baguette\Documents\"
    WeekFolder = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    
    Workbooks.Open (FolderPath & WeekFolder & "\L060.xlsx")

End Sub
```